# how to understand word "go"

Tags: sentence-meaning

[image]

I do not fully understand the meaning of the underlined sentences.
In my view, if word GO is omitted, the sentence has the same meaning as previous, for example, The plate went crashing to the floor=The plate crashed to floor.
I think I am wrong, but not sure the difference between two sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it allows us know which direction, from the speakers perspective, the subject is going. Let's contrast `go` with `come`.

> The rocket **went** screeching through the air.
>
> The rocket **came** screeching through the air.

Also it allows us to combine different types of movement.

> The bullet **spiraled** in air. (only spiraling same location)
>
> The bullet **went spiraling** through air. (spiraling and changing location)

It also emphasizes the movement.

> The plate **crashed** to floor. (I envision the plate crashing)
>
> The plate **went crashing** to the floor. (I envision the plate moving towards the floor then crashing into it)

Answer (score 0):

"Went" is past tense of go: go/went/gone. "The plate went crashing to the floor" is very similar to "The plate crashed to the floor", with perhaps a little more emphasis on the current action "went crashing" than the past tense "crashed".